# Integration over bounded regions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have to evaluate the following integral
\begin{align*}
\int_Ee^{x^2-2xy+10y^2}dA,
\end{align*}
where $E=\{(x,y)\ |\ x^2-2xy+10y^2\leq1\}$. I already evaluated the integral and got $\frac{\pi(e-1)}{3}$. Here is how I did it:

$E$ is an ellipse, so I calculated a parametrization via $(x,y)=r(a_1,b_1)\cos(t)+r(a_2,b_2)\sin(t)$, where $(a_1,b_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2)$ are conjugated diameters of $E$. Then I used a change of variables.

My question now is: Is there another method that does not use that $E$ has this particular shape? What if $E$ is some ugly region, or $E$ has nothing to do with the integrand? (Here the exponent of $e$ under the integral sign and $E$ share the same term).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem you attacked was chosen such that the technique you employed (which by the way is excellent) would work.  In the general case such integrals do not work out in terms of elementary functions. Consider, for example, $\int_Se^{-(x^2+y^2)}dA$ with $C =\{(x,y) : |x|\leq 1 \wedge |y| \leq 1\}$. That integral over a square area can't be expressed without $\erf$ functions.

Comment: Ah ok, so you're saying that integrals of this form cannot be evaluated directly using some elegant powerful method unless the region and integrand are chosen sufficiently "nice"?